# Onclick not working on list in iphone using html

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, sup

I am creating a list dynamically.I want to call a function on onclick event of the list.In the list I am having a  tag  tag a

tag.The onclick is working on android and blackberry but not on the iphone.This is the sample code

```
 htmlOutput +='<a style="display: block;" onclick="getAreaCodeClicked('+area+');">
<li style="overflow: hidden;>
<img src="Star.png" style="margin:0px;float:left;" />
<p style="white-space:nowrap;">
   <label style="font-size:11px;color:black;">'+officeName+'</label><br>
   <label style="font-size:8px;color:#A1A1A1;">'+officeLocation+'</label>
</p>
</li></a>
```

can anyone please tell me what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone browser does not use `onclick` events, it uses `ontouch`. Look in to that event instead.

Comment: Hi David.I have binded this event with the tap. So I think this is not the problem. I think it is related to applying the click event on the whole list.