# Cannot touch html form using iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, django

I have a form (in template file) in a Django app, like this:

```
<li>
  <form action="{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}?{{ redirect_querystring }}" method="get">
     <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}">
     <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().submit();return false;"><img class="loggin" src="../img/fb-loggin.png" alt="loggin"></a>
  </form>
</li>
```

The problem is this form works on most devices except touch devices like iPhone, iPad...
Please give me an idea. Many thanks! :)

Take a look to my website for more details: http://truyenyy.com

Comment: See these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This word for me! xD

```
    $('#sex').bind('touchstart click', function(){
       $(this).parent().submit();
       return false
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `<a href="javascript:void(0);"` instead of `<a href="#"`. Also take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450696/onclick-not-working-on-list-in-iphone-using-html)

Comment: the `return false` part of the js will prevent any link being followed, so the href is meaningless.